# split to preg_split alternative with same behavior

Tags: php, split, preg-split

I have the following line:

```
$ar = split("\r?\n", $str);
```

Because split is deprecated I search for an alternarive. And tried:

```
$ar = preg_split("/\r?\n/", $str);
```

Is this the same as the above?

The main question is not if preg_split is an possible alternative for the deprecated function split. The question is if the result with the regex I used for preg_split is the same as the one used for split

EDIT: I tested some use cases and it seems to be equivalent.

Comment: Test and tell us.

Comment: What was the previous output ? Is it different now ? Looks like a legit regex and the documentation recommend to use functions such as `preg_split()`

Comment: It's the same. You can also use `preg_split('/\R/', $str);` or `preg_split('/\R/u', $str);` for any utf-8 line-breaks.